# Oracle Query Help - Sub-query for grouping

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have table with following columns and data entries (sample)

```
EID    ROW_NUM    ROW_VALUE
SM      1           E
SM      2           E
PM      2           E
SM      3           E
AM      3           S 
PM      3           E
SM      4           E
AM      4           S
SM      5           S
AM      5           E
PM      5           E
SM      6           S
AM      6           E
PM      6           E
NM      6           S
```

I have to group by row_num & remove records matching on following combinations (exact)

1. SM=E AND PM=E  , 
   this should remove rows related to row_num=2 only & 
   retain row_num=3. Although it includes this combination 
   it is not exact match.
2. SM=S AND AM=E AND PM=E,
   this should remove rows related to row_num=5 only & 
   retain row_num=6. Although it includes this combination 
   it is not exact match.

I am looking how to formulate a query that can remove or at least return back row_num for such combinations ?

I can add more info if required

Comment: to make sure i understand correctly, for #1 ONLY in case same ROW_NUM appears twice, once with ( EID=SM and ROW_VALUE=E) and second row with (EID=PM and ROW_VALUE=E) , but if only single row exists for this ROW_NUM then its valid ?

Comment: To answer your question, it should be exact combination. For example, data with row_num=1, although has SM=E does not have data for PM=E. Hence it is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should do it:

```
select distinct row_num
from example_table t1
where
    not (
        exits ( select 1 
                from example_table t2 
                where t2.row_num=t1.row_num and t2.eid='SM' and t2.row_value='E')
        and
        exits ( select 1 
                from example_table t3 
                where t3.row_num=t1.row_num and t3.eid='PM' and t3.row_value='E')
    )
    and
    not (
        exits ( select 1 
                from example_table t4 
                where t4.row_num=t1.row_num and t4.eid='SM' and t4.row_value='S')
        and
        exits ( select 1 
                from example_table t5 
                where t5.row_num=t1.row_num and t5.eid='AM' and t5.row_value='E')
        and
        exits ( select 1 
                from example_table t6 
                where t6.row_num=t1.row_num and t6.eid='PM' and t6.row_value='E')
    );
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try and post back a reply. I have 58 different combinations to try. Will try at least 10 of them to verify if results are correct.